# double summation with square root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is below-average question on this platform, but I am confused over this double summation with a square root:

$$\sum_{p=1}^2\sum_{q=1}^2\sqrt[2]{(p-.5)^2+(q-.5)^2}$$

Does it give an answer of $\sqrt{10}$ or $5.9907$?

Comment: Just write out the sum, it's four terms.

Comment: I did that but i am confused over the appearance of square root.If it would be four terms of $\sqrt{()+()+...}$ or $\sqrt()$+$\sqrt()$+...

Comment: The second one, you can't just combine under the square root like the first one.

Comment: @vonbrand: yes sir,i got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by vondbrand, just develop the summation. Start with the inner sum; so you have first $$\sum_{p=1}^2\sum_{q=1}^2\sqrt[2]{(p-\frac{1}{2})^2+(q-\frac{1}{2})^2}=\sum _{p=1}^2  \left(\sqrt{\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{1}{4}}+\sqrt{\left(p-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{9}{4}}\right)$$
Then do the same for the outer sum and you should arrive to   $$2 \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{10}$$ which is almost $5.99017$

Comment: You are welcome !